# EdgeDriver is sending two letters via SendKeys

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, sendkeys

I am using Selenium WebDriver 3.0 to perform some automate tests. I have simple login page where I input login email, password and log in. When I am using EdgeDriver it sends two same letters instead of one to password field. I really dont know why, because other drivers dont have this problem (IE, FF, CH). This is part of code

```
edgedriver.FindElement(By.Id("IDEmail")).Clear();
edgedriver.FindElement(By.Id("IDEmail")).SendKeys("test@test.com");
edgedriver.FindElement(By.Id("IDPass")).Clear();
edgedriver.FindElement(By.Id("IDPass")).SendKeys("1");
edgedriver.FindElement(By.Id("IDLogin")).Click();
```

this will end up with 11 in password field and clicking on login fail because wrong password. Any clues why EdgeDriver is doing it?. Using version Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Edge is form filling the password. If the username/password is saved for the test website, then even though you clear the field, Edge will form-fill the password (in this case the string "1") and then you will sendKeys("1"), resulting in "11".

An immediate workaround would be to either remove the saved login credentials or login and let form fill handle the user credentials for you.